# Unable to use set hotkey in UI with autokey linux

Tags: autokey

I am able to run scripts using autokey-run command, however when I try to set up auto key scripts with the UI it is unable to listen to my key presses. And simple is just waiting for me to press a key as I am hammering the keyboard. Any ideas?

I am on **ubuntu** linux